# Why is userInfo not present when user clicks notification?

Tags: swift, macos

I use the following function to display notifications (that part works).

```swift
func showNotification(_ body: String, _ config: Config){
  let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
  content.body = body
  content.userInfo = ["logFile": config.logFile]
  let request = UNNotificationRequest(
    identifier: UUID().uuidString,
    content: content,
    trigger: nil
  )
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error:Error?) in
    if error != nil {
      print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Could not add notification")
    }
  }
}
```

When the app is not running and a user clicks on a notification in the notification center, I use the following function to try to get `userInfo`, but the property is not present.

```swift
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let alert = NSAlert.init()
    alert.messageText = String(describing: notification.userInfo)
    alert.runModal()
  }
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out why!

I was trying to get `userInfo` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, but the right way to get `userInfo` is using `userNotificationCenter` (both if app is running or not).

```swift
func userNotificationCenter(
  _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
  didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
  withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void
) {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let alert = NSAlert.init()
    alert.messageText = String(describing: response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
    alert.runModal()
  }
}
```